# NDepend CQL reports methods as using Boxing/Unboxing incorrectly

Tags: c#-4.0, generics, boxing, ndepend

In NDepend 4 (v4.1.0.6871) I am using the default Design query "Boxing/unboxing should be avoided":

```
warnif percentage > 5 from m in Application.Methods where
    m.IsUsingBoxing ||
    m.IsUsingUnboxing
select new { m, m.NbLinesOfCode, m.IsUsingBoxing, m.IsUsingUnboxing }
```

It is reporting the following method (Inspired by and stolen from Jon Skeet's [MiscUtil](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/)) as using boxing:

```
public static void ThrowIfNull<T>(this T target, string name) where T : class
{
  if (target == null)
  {
    throw new ArgumentNullException(name ?? string.Empty);
  }
}
```

I don't understand how this method is possibly using boxing. I am not using a cast anywhere.

I tried the following version just in case the null coalescing operator was using boxing somehow behind the scenes:

```
public static void ThrowIfNull<T>(this T target, string name) where T : class
{
  if (target == null)
  {
    throw new ArgumentNullException(name);
  }
}
```

... but I had no luck with that either, NDepend still reported that the method was using boxing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By decompiling this method with .NET Reflector we see that indeed this method is using the `box` IL instruction. Despite the fact that you are using the `class` generic constraint, the compiler still emits a box instruction for verifiability issue. More explanation on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475576/why-the-compiler-emits-box-instructions-to-compare-instances-of-a-reference-type).

```
.method public hidebysig static void ThrowIfNull<class T>(!!T target, string name) cil managed
{
    .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute::.ctor()
    .maxstack 2
    .locals init (
        [0] bool flag)
    L_0000: nop 
    L_0001: ldarg.0 
    L_0002: box !!T   <-----------
    L_0007: ldnull 
    L_0008: ceq 
    L_000a: ldc.i4.0 
    L_000b: ceq 
    L_000d: stloc.0 
    L_000e: ldloc.0 
    L_000f: brtrue.s L_0022
    L_0011: nop 
    L_0012: ldarg.1 
    L_0013: dup 
    L_0014: brtrue.s L_001c
    L_0016: pop 
    L_0017: ldsfld string [mscorlib]System.String::Empty
    L_001c: newobj instance void [mscorlib]System.ArgumentNullException::.ctor(string)
    L_0021: throw 
    L_0022: ret 
}
```