# C# emits box/unbox when assigning generic types?

Tags: c#, boxing, generic-constraints

I just stumbled upon a weird IL code emitted for the following samples:

```
class Sample
{
    void Foo<T,U>(T t, U u) where U : T { t = u; }
}
```

The IL emitted for the body of Foo is

```
IL_0001: ldarg.2      // u
IL_0002: box          !!1/*U*/
IL_0007: unbox.any    !!0/*T*/
IL_000c: starg.s      t
```

So my question: Why does it emit an unboxing/boxing operation? I would imagine that the conversation does never need any boxing, as its either a reference type in the first place or the very same data type anyway.

Even weirder, even if I explicitly say the type parameter are reference types, that does not change the emitted code in any way:

```
class Sample
{
    void Foo<T, U>(T t, U u) where U : class, T where T : class { t = u; }
}
```

(IL output is the same)

So.. why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why the compiler emits box instructions to compare instances of a reference type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475576/why-the-compiler-emits-box-instructions-to-compare-instances-of-a-reference-type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`T` could be a reference type (interface, `object` or `System.ValueType`) while `U` is a struct e.g.

```
Foo<IConvertible, int>(1, 2);
Foo<object, int>("foo", 2);
```

Comment: OK, you are right about the first sample. What about the second sample that still emits a boxing conversation? I explicitly require T and U to be reference types.

Comment: @Imi - See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475576/why-the-compiler-emits-box-instructions-to-compare-instances-of-a-reference-type) for why boxing is required.